# How to adjust strike that’s too small for metal jam?

Tags: door-frame

I am installing new Schlage lock set. Problem is the included Schlage strike is much smaller/shorter than the drilled out rectangle space in the metal door jam. Only one screw hole matches other hole is about 1/2 inch too short. How do I adjust?

Comment: Talking about the strike plate or the latch assembly? ... put the old plate back.

Comment: Your new door knob should work fine with the old strike plate.

Comment: @Alaskaman Geez! It did. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Strike plates are rarely proprietary to the door knob itself. Most are the same size, some slightly different in size or screw hole placement but the catch of the door knob should fit in the catch hole  of all of them if they are lined up right.

Since you have metal door jamb it is not easy to modify your jamb.

Try using the old strike plate, it should work just fine.

*Credit to Mazura for thinking of it first.*

Comment: I don't throw anything away (doesn't everybody have three buckets of lock parts? ;) and I usually don't pull the plate off if I can avoid it; too many times pieces of trim caked on with paint have come off with it, even if you use a knife to cut around it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have use a longer screw for the hole that is not lining-up. I'm assuming it's over the opening on the jamb for the latch. If so, you can drill a hole into the door jamb to allow a longer screw to screw into the wall stud. You may need to back-up the pate if it doesn't have part of the jamb to support it when screwed down.

You may be able to replace the original strike plate with a Dead bolt strike plate. These are usually longer than standard door plate. There may be a problem in that there is no curved lip and the latch opening is slightly wider.